# How to lookupfield in lines of Client script API 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

i need to pick a field from item master record. The item type is sometimes service item and sometimes itemgroup. There is some issue in record 'type'  and 'id'. Please help.

```
My Code:

  var govFeeFieldInside = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.ITEM,
    id: item_,
    columns:
      [
        'custitem2'//govFeeInItemMaster
      ]
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lookupFields` is only for body-level fields. To retrieve sublist data from any record, you will need to either perform a search or load the record.